# what are the correct steps for text data pre-processing

Tags: python, text, data-science

I am working on an Airbnb dataset to predict the review scores of the customers(score ranges from 0 to 100) given the transport information(text data).

One typical transport information is: Convenient bus stops are just down the block, if you're headed downtown or further afield to explore.  Zip cars are also strategically located on Queen Anne hill.

I am new to data science!

Below are the **data preprocessing steps** that I am using. **Could anyone tell me if they are correct?**

preprocessing steps for train data:

1. convert to lower case
2. remove punctuation
3. remove stopwords
4. remove common/rare words identified from data exploration
5. spelling correction
6. Lemmatization
7. calculate the tf-idf vector with the following code:

```
   tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
   train_X = tfidf.fit_transform(train_X)
```

preprocessing steps for test data:

1. convert to lower case
2. remove punctuation
3. remove stopwords
4. spelling correction
5. Lemmatization
6. calculate the tf-idf vector with the following code:

```
   test_X = tfidf.transform(test_X)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the forum! I can add some:

- Converting all numbers to their word equivalents (to avoid having some in numbers and some in words). You can also just convert all numbers to a special word like NUM by using a regular expression.
- Expanding abbreviations. Maybe a user used HH.RR and another, Human Resources.
- Stemming: that is, eliminating affixes (suffixed, prefixes, infixes, circumfixes) from a word in order to obtain a word stem (e.g. **eating --> eat**)
- Strip extra white spaces if applicable
- Remove "stop words" like "the", "and", "a", but also the most common words used in your reviews. So, first check the distribution of words in the text, and filter the top (meaningless!) words out.
- Delete noise like headers, footers, HTML tags and so on.

If this answered your question, please don't forget to press the checkmark button on the left of my answer in order to accept it.